# SQL Server DateTime cast from VarChar

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, type-conversion

I've got a table with 9 million records.  Each one has a "BirthDate" field that is stored as a varchar.  I'm trying to select all where the birthdate is 25 years or less (all people 25 or under).  It's failing, because somewhere in this monstrosity of a table, there is an invalid value.

```
select COUNT(*) from LeadSplit where CAST(LeadSplit.Birthdate as datetime) > DATEADD(yy, -26, getdate())  and Birthdate is not null
```

The error is:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I'm at a loss as to how to find the row with the invalid value, and also, how to deal with it.  I would like to just ignore it or fix it.

Comment: Are the `Birthdate` values (at least meant to be) in some consistent format? Such as `yyyymmdd` or something?

Comment: They are supposed to be, yes.  In mm/dd/yyyy.  All the ones I have personally viewed have been.

Comment: Obviously the best solution is to convert the column to a real datetime. That would prevent this problem in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas, it sure would.  Unfortunately, I don't have control over the population of this database.  I just get to write some queries against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could *try* to find the offending rows by doing something like:

```
SELECT (some ID), Birthdate
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ISDATE(Birthdate) = 0
```

This might not work for all cases - but it might give you a starting point.

Comment: Freaking awesome.  I added an IS NOT NULL too, and it returned 5 rows.  I updated those suckers to null and now the query returns.  Whew!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is that one or more of the dates cannot be parsed given the DateFormat setting.

```
Set DateFormat MDY
GO
Select Count(*)
From LeadSplit
Where Case
        When IsDate(BirthDate) = 0 Then 0
        When BirthDate >= DateAdd(yyyy,-25,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) Then 1
        End = 1
```

Comment: @Martin (Won't perform great of course, but would guarantee executing).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CONVERT instead of CAST and explicit specify date format. [MSDN Article about CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)